# update JSON file with php and slim

Tags: php, json, api, composer-php, slim

Hi I am trying to create an update function using existing json data in a separate given file:

people.json:

```
[{
"firstname": "Smith",
"surname":   "Johnson"
}, {
"firstname": "Sabrina",
"surname":   "Khalifa"
}, {
"firstname": "Joe",
"surname":   "Higgins"
}]
```

The display function works and just GET's all data above.

```
 public function display() {
    $data = $this->container->get('data');
    $people = $data->load('people');
    $this->render('people', ['people' => $people]);
}
```

The container and methods like load are defined in other classes.   I would like to grab "firstname" and "surname" and update and i'm clearly doing a lot of things wrong in this but it just wont update:

PeopleController.php:

```
public function update() {
    $data = $this->container->get('data');
    $people = $data->load('people');
    $this->save('people', ['people' => $people]);
}
```

Index.php:

```
 $app->get('/',  'App\\PeopleController:display'); //get all people
 $app->put('/',  'App\\PeopleController:update'); //trying to update
```

HTML in use:

```
<form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
    </tr>
    {% for person in people %} 
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="people[][firstname]" value="{{ person.firstname }}" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="people[][surname]" value="{{ person.surname }}" /></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="OK" /> 
</form>
```

DataLoader:

```
class DataLoader {

protected $path;

public function __construct($path) {
    $this->path = $path;
}

/**
 * Load data from the requested file
 *
 * @param string $file Filename
 * @return array Decoded file contents
 */
public function load($file) {
    $path = $this->getPath($file);

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        return json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);
    }

    return [];
}

/**
 * Save data to the requested file
 *
 * @param string $file Filename
 * @param array  $data Contents to save to file
 */
public function save($file, array $data) {
    file_put_contents(json_encode($this->getPath($file)), $data);
}

protected function getPath($file) {
    return $this->path . "/$file.json";
}
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code in data

Comment: do you mean database? if so there is no database we are just working with the above json file. There are 3 "Controllers" which are classes and include functions for loading file and saving file/data etc if thats what you mean?

Comment: `$data = $this->container->get('data');` implies that there is a class registered with the DIC, possibly called `Data`?

Comment: Please check I have updated the question added Dataloader class and added update() function that I am currently trying to run